# Is it good practice to use LINQ often?

Tags: linq

LINQ is extremely powerful and can be used highly in code. But is it best practice to use it?

Comment: Can you name some disadvantages?

Comment: Best practice to achieve what? LINQ can add readability.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Technically it's a little slower than hand-crafted code :-) And LINQ creates new collections, while often you could re-use the source collection in a destructive way. But in the end, unless you REALLY have a problem with speed, LINQ is the way to go

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a good idea to use it when it makes the code clearer and simpler to maintain, and when you're not in any of the situations where the performance of LINQ is too slow for your needs.

You haven't specified whether you're talking about LINQ to Objects or LINQ to SQL etc, but I know there are situations where the latter *has* proved too slow for some high traffic sites, and they've moved off it... but only after it's been *shown* to be an issue. LINQ to Objects will often have a very small performance hit compared with "hard-coding" the same logic, but that's even less likely to be a real problem.

Of course LINQ can certainly be overused, and I've seen people reaching for a LINQ solution when there are far more appropriate ways of achieving the same thing - so don't try to use it *everywhere* you possibly can. Just use it where it clearly helps.

Answer (score 4):

the declarative nature of linq is one of its strongest features. Almost always this makes your code more readable and maintainable, so yes, unless there is a compelling performance reason not to, I'd say that it is best practice.